# Nested routes vue default

Tags: vue.js

I have this root vue component

```
<template>
<router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Router-view should match either **/main**, **/login** urls as shown in the routes below

```
{path: '/login',component: 'login.vue'}
{path: '/main',component: 'main.vue', children:[
  {path: '/mainchild1',component: 'mainchild1.vue'},
  {path: '/mainchild2',component: 'mainchild2.vue'
]}
```

The main component is a sidebar and a content-view that should be populated with /main children:

```
    //Main.vue
    <template>
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    </template>
```

The idea here is to keep a sidebar and render aside either

1. mainchild1.vue (on **/main/mainchild1**)
2. mainchild2.vue (on **/main/mainchild1**)

Now, if no route is specified in the url i want to redirect to the main component (/main) but with at least the sub view populated (either mainchild1 or mainchild2).

Here is where i am struggling, any help/hints is appreciated.

I tried to redirect on "/" to /main/mainchild1 but it simply renders the root  content, with the mainchild1.vue so removing the sidebar.

I am still learning vue and probably missing some steps in routing tecnique.

**UPDATED**

Ok, it seemes that i should remove the / from the child elements. This way it works.

To decide if this could be of any help or i should delete this
Thanks
Davide

Comment: By removing `/` from the child route, the child route becomes relative to the parent & finally forms `/<parent-routes>/<child-route>`, you can achieve same as proposed in below solution by starting the path from `/` eg. `/<parent>/<child>` as an alternative.

Comment: Also, you had mentioned, "you tried to redirect `/` to `/main/mainchild1` but it simply renders the root content". To solve this as proposed in the below solution you can use `redirect` key in the route object to redirect `/` to `/main/mainchild1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

route.js

```
[
  path: '/', redirect: '/main/mainchild1',
  path: '/main', redirect: '/main/mainchild1', component: 'main.vue', children: [
    { path: '/main/mainchild1', component: mainchild1.vue },
    { path: '/main/mainchild2', component: mainchild2.vue }
  ] 
]
```

app.vue

```
<template>
 <sidebar v-if="isLoggedIn"/>
 <router-view></router-view> <!-- components mapped with route '/' or '/main' will render here -->
</template>
```

main.vue

```
<template>
 <router-view></router-view> <!-- components mapped with route '/main/mainchild1' or '/main/mainchild2' will render here -->
</template>
```

Comment: The problem is that app.vue should not have the sidebar in case of the login page

Comment: In that case, you can add `v-if` directive with a `boolean` value returning true/false on the basis of the login state (getter/computed). Updated the code according to this.

Comment: `v-if` directive will prevent `sidebar` to render on the dom in case user is not logged in.